# accessing vector elements inside a for loop, comparison of some ways

Tags: optimization, c++11, vector, benchmarking

I wrote a little benchmarking program to check some ways to access data stored in a vector.
I used tww nested for loop to confront 
A) create a reference to an object of the vector for each iteration of the first loop and use that reference in a second for loop
B) create a pointer, store in that pointer a reference to to an object of the vector for each iteration of the first loop and use that pointer in a second for loop 
C) access directly the vector object with the [] operator
D) use auto& in the first loop

Such couple of nested for loops was itself nested in an other loop together with a timing function.
Running the test several times, with the for loop going from 0 to 100, I got the same timing results for all these method, always around 0.150 seconds, with a fluctuation of 0.02%.

My questions are:

1) is my test correct?

2) is there some optimization/different approach I missed, which could be faster?

Here's my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ratio>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;


struct my_struct{

    vector<float> data;

    my_struct(int N, float x){

        for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
            data.push_back(cos(x+i));
        }
    }

    void work(){
        for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++){
            data[i]=data[i]*data[i];
         }
    }

};

int main(){
int N=100;
vector<my_struct> stuff;
for(int k=0; k<N; ++k){
    stuff.push_back( my_struct(100,sin(k)) );
}

vector<duration<double>> results_t1,results_t2,results_t3,results_t4;
high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
for(int k=0; k<N; ++k){
    int which=0; //this is used to choose what method of access will be used
    switch(which){
        case 0:{ //pointer
            my_struct * thing=NULL;
            for( int i=0; i<N;++i){
                high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
                for( int j=0; j<N;++j){
                    thing =&stuff[j];
                    for( int jj=0; jj<N;++jj)
                        thing->work();
                }
                duration<double> time_span = duration_cast<duration<double>>(t2 - t1);
                results_t1.push_back(time_span);
                t1=t2;
            }
            break;
        }

        case 1:{    //direct access
            for( int i=0; i<N;++i){
                high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
                for( int j=0; j<N;++j){
                    for( int jj=0; jj<N;++jj)
                        stuff[j].work();
                }
                duration<double> time_span = duration_cast<duration<double>>(t2 - t1);
                results_t2.push_back(time_span);
                t1=t2;
            }
            break;
        }

        case 2:{    //auto reference
            for( int i=0; i<N;++i){
                high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
                for( auto& temp : stuff){
                    for( int jj=0; jj<N;++jj)
                        temp.work();
                }
                duration<double> time_span = duration_cast<duration<double>>(t2 - t1);
                results_t3.push_back(time_span);
                t1=t2;
            }
            break;
        }
        case 3:{    //reference
            for( int i=0; i<N;++i){
                high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
                for( int j=0; j<N;++j){
                    my_struct & temp =stuff[j];
                    for( int jj=0; jj<N;++jj)
                        temp.work();
                }
                duration<double> time_span = duration_cast<duration<double>>(t2 - t1);
                results_t4.push_back(time_span);
                t1=t2;
            }
            break;
        }

    }
}
double temp=0;
for(auto& t : results_t1){
temp+=t.count();
}
temp=temp/N;
std::cout << "pointer " << temp << " seconds.";
std::cout << std::endl;

temp=0.0;
for(auto& t : results_t2){
temp+=t.count();
}
temp=temp/N;
std::cout << "direct " << temp << " seconds.";
std::cout << std::endl;

temp=0.0;
for(auto& t : results_t3){
temp+=t.count();
}
temp=temp/N;
std::cout << "auto reference " << temp << " seconds.";
std::cout << std::endl;

    temp=0.0;
for(auto& t : results_t4){
temp+=t.count();
}
temp=temp/N;
std::cout << "reference " << temp << " seconds.";
std::cout << std::endl;

cin.get();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tag for `optimization` also if you need good answers.

Comment: @UchiaItachi Your comment seems to imply that only optimization questions get good answers ;)

Comment: @Borgleader: If you want good answers *about optimization*, tagging with [tag:optimization] does seem like the obvious thing to do.

Comment: Could you format your code better? Markdown doesn't like tabs.

Comment: @Rapptz I corrected the formatting for the struct. The code inside the main seems ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect similar results for each of the methods. The time isn't spent in loops, it'll be spent in the math functions `sin` and `cos`. Compiler optimizations such as loop invariants will make `case 1` as fast as the other loops and there isn't anything to choose between those others regarding performance.

For style, prefer the keep it simple which will aid maintainability and reduce bugs in the long run. I'd go with `case 1` direct access on that basis. Introducing temporaries to try to help the compiler won't actually help the compiler.

Comment: Thanks, "Introducing temporaries to try to help the compiler won't actually help the compiler" it's a very good paradigm to remember.